# Tracking service companies assets uisng Mapbox

Tags: ionic-framework

We are starting with developing an Ionic app which will be used for asset tracking using MapBox. Here is a good description of what we want to do https://blog.mapbox.com/how-to-do-asset-tracking-cb27ba2da5ab

The first step is to find a solution for pushing location and other attribute data from a mobile device to a Stream Processor that will listen for the data. Does anyone know what service or plugin we could use for that?

We are using ionic for our development of the mobile app

We are new at this and here is how map box support described the process

> Blockquote The device/hardware would need to its own software with an API service that can PUSH location and attribute data from. The Stream Processor listens for this information and can collect it on their end (e.g. PubNub, Pusher, etc.). The Database can then be used to store this info. All of this is considered the API Gateway and Mapbox is the final piece where you can poll or process info from the API Gateway so you can visualize it on your map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PubNub's Publish Subscribe API will allow you to do this. In your Ionic app, you can do a PubNub publish after you create a free account and grab API keys. Below is the TS or JS code.

First [sign up for a PubNub account](https://dashboard.pubnub.com/signup?devrel_so=54199600) (free up to 1 million transactions per month).

**Pub/Sub**

[image]

Installing the SDK in your Ionic 3 project

```
npm install pubnub --save
```

TypeScript or JavaScript

```js
const pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : 'your-publish-api-key-here',
    subscribeKey : 'your-subscribe-api-key-here'
});

// publish a JSON message to all subscribers
pubnub.publish({
    channel : 'my-awesome-channel-name',
    message: { hello: 'world' }
}, function(status, response) {
    // Handle error here
})

// any device in the world will receive publishes in realtime
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: ['my-awesome-channel-name']
});

// do something with the message that you receive
pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(event) {
        // event.message === { hello: 'world' }
    }
});
```

If a subscriber device is not online while publishes occur, you can fetch past published messages using the [PubNub Storage & Playback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history) history API.

In case you need to log these messages to a database on your server, there is a guide for doing that with PubNub Functions:

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/the-right-way-to-log-all-messages-to-a-private-database/

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking  for